# Can I use another pandas dataframe(from csv file) to cycle through the different lines to change a colum in a pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
tables.loc[tables.Date == '2021-06-01 00:09:00', 'Valuable'] = 1
```

I wanna replace the '2021-06-01 00:09:00' with values from a csv file that looks like:

```
2021-06-01 00:09:00
2021-06-01 00:04:00
```

I somehow need to cycle through every line in the csv file so it changes it accordingly. "tables" dataframe(csv using .to_csv) looks like:

```
Valuable,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,EMA8,EMA14,EMA50,ht,sar,MorningStar,Engulfing
0,2021-06-01 00:00:00,353.37,353.51,351.08,351.3,,,,,,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:01:00,351.41,354.23,351.31,353.25,,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:02:00,353.23,358.36,353.19,357.5,,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:03:00,357.5,357.73,356.26,356.81,,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:04:00,356.82,358.95,356.17,357.61,,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:05:00,357.73,359.59,356.86,359.15,,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:06:00,359.11,359.23,358.2,358.65,,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:07:00,358.64,359.29,357.95,358.0,356.53,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:08:00,358.0,360.0,358.0,359.47,357.19,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:09:00,359.5,360.5,358.34,358.67,357.52,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:10:00,358.74,360.94,358.65,360.57,358.19,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:11:00,360.59,361.0,359.64,360.03,358.6,,,,351.08,0,0
0,2021-06-01 00:12:00,359.95,360.55,359.42,359.61,358.83,,,,351.08,0,0
```

EDIT:
Got it working using:

```
for (index_label, row_series) in timestamp.iterrows():
tables.loc[tables.Date == row_series.values[0], 'Valuable'] = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried the function `iloc()` or iterating the dataframe by `iterrows()`?

Comment: Actually havent tried that because I have no idea how

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method without looping, try:

```
tables.loc[tables['Valuable'] == 0, 'Date'] = 1
```

**Example output:**

```
   Valuable Date    Open    High     Low   Close  EMA8  EMA14  EMA50  ht  \
0         0    1  353.37  353.51  351.08  351.30   NaN    NaN    NaN NaN   
1         0    1  351.41  354.23  351.31  353.25   NaN    NaN    NaN NaN   
2         0    1  353.23  358.36  353.19  357.50   NaN    NaN    NaN NaN   
3         0    1  357.50  357.73  356.26  356.81   NaN    NaN    NaN NaN   
4         0    1  356.82  358.95  356.17  357.61   NaN    NaN    NaN NaN 
.....
.......
.........
```